# is there a way to get the insert into to work properly in pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I can not figure out why I can not get my cursor.execute statement to work. I do not get any Python errors however the code continues to fail  the try command. I am connected to SQL and I can print a list of column in the table. Here is my code.

```
import pyodbc

# Connect to the database

connection = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=******;'
    r'DATABASE=****;'
    r'UID=****;'
    r'PWD=*****'
    )
try:
    # Create a cursor
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # Execute a SQL statement
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employee table (FName, SSN) VALUES (?, ?)", "john", "123-123-1234")
    connection.commit()
    print("success")
except pyodbc.Error:
    print("error")
    connection.rollback()

# Close the cursor and connection
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

I get a 42000 error when I print out the error but the syntax looks to be all correct.

Comment: `INSERT INTO employee (FName, SSN)....` (i.e. there's a leftover `.. table ...`  in your SQL statement which should not be there and is a syntax error).

Comment: employee table is the name of the table

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employee table (FName, SSN) VALUES (?, ?)", "john", "123-123-1234")
```

I see two problems here.

First, the syntax for INSERT should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

But instead of `tablename`, you have `employee table`.  If `employee` is the name of the table, then just use that; you don't need the extra word `table` hanging out there.

Second, you're passing two arguments `"john", "123-123-1234"` to the execute function, but this is wrong.  It should be *one* argument, which is a list/tuple containing all the desired values, like so:

```
cursor.execute("...", ("john", "123-123-1234"))
```

Comment: employee table is the name of the table

Comment: @JustinPerry In that case, you need to use special quoting around `employee table` .  I'm not sure what the exact syntax is for SQL Server; I would start by trying backticks `\`employee table\``

Comment: Square brackets might also work.  `[employee table]`

Comment: I just looked it up and it was brackets thank you, wish I could upvote you

Comment: @JustinPerry you can, by clicking the green checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#passing-parameters